# Django Rest Framework Not Returning Full JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble retrieving the full JSON Response when executing a GET request on an API I am building with DRF. If I include pagination and retrieve, say, 100 results then I receive the full JSON Response. If I do not use pagination, and would like to retrieve a few thousand results, then the server simply cuts off at a seemingly random spot and does not return full JSON. For instance, it may return {"hi": "hel instead of returning {"hi":"hello"}. DRF reports this as a 200 response code, so it seems as though it executes properly.

The code for my view looks like:

```
class RepresentativeListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Representative.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RepresentativeSerializer
```

The code for my serializer looks like:

```
class RepresentativeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Representative
        fields = (
            'bioguide_id',
            'stats',
            'leadership_score',
            'ideology_score',
       )
```

Could anyone understand why a full JSON response would not be coming through?

Comment: Hi, Has anybody found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your Apache / Nginx / whatever you use web server.
It may close the connection if the application didn't respond on time.
Check your web server logs and the time it takes for the application to render the response vs the server timeout.

Comment: I am using the local server built in django (python manage.py runserver). Whenever a request is made, even when it returns incomplete JSON, it logs a 200 status code.